# How does browser highlight the word/sentence while reading aloud?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, windows

In the new Edge browser (chromium based) there is option for text-to-speech, while reading the page it highlights the sentence and word being read, something like this - [image]

In the past I had a simple TTS app for Windows, there I achieved highlighting the sentence by placing each sentence in `<span id=''>` tag with unique id value, and then passing the sentence to TTS engine with the same Id, when TTS engine started reading I would get a call-back with the Id and then I would highlight the entire tag with the given Id.

How does Edge browser do it? Or how is it done generally by similar applications? How do they highlight the sentence and the word? I inspected the page while reading, at-least I didn't find any changes in the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edge also does it in a similar way except that it encloses the text in  tags. Refer to the attached screenshot. In the picture you can clearly see that the text currently being read is enclosed in this tag and styles are applied using CSS.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Given they are also doing something similar means I am an on the right path.